# How to Hide button using identifier (Restoration ID)

Tags: iphone, ios, identifier

I added a button to a view using storyboard(not programatically) and i want to hide that button by calling a function. Is it possible to hide that button programatically using identifier..
--Thanx

can't I use something similar to  this: if(button.identifier isEqualToString:@"btnMyButton")

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to make use of the `tag` property of the button. In INterface builder set the tag value of the button.

```
if(button.tag == Button_tag_value)
 {      
     button.hidden = YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
yourButton.hidden = YES;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create an IBOutlet for the button. You can then use the IBOutlet to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tag to the button in the IB. Tag works as an identifier in hierarchy of views. In your view controller, on you `self.view` (assuming the button is subview of parent view) object you can send `viewWithTag` message with the Tag of the button you added in IB. This will return you the UIButton object and using the `hidden` property, you can hide it.
This does not require any IB connection of IBAction to be defined.